# Single transistor Amplifier analysis (Q point values)

Tags: transistors, amplifier

Could somebody please check to see if what I have done is right? I posted a similar question a few days ago and someone said V(CE) is equal to V(CC)/2. Is it ok to do this?

So I got V(CEQ) = 6V and then I(C)=1mA

I tried to solve I(B) on the left side first but got a negative value for it? So that can't be right.

I don't need any help with part b)

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Task 1** - find Ib.

We know that VBE is 0.7V (given).{*quick check - is this possible with the given values? - without the base connected R2 would produce a drop of about 0.75V  - this is a good result because we can always drop this voltage by taking current into the base*}.

For VBE = 0.7 and R2 = 6.3k by Ohm's law I(R2) = 0.7/R2 = 0.11111 mA

The 11.3 volt drop (12 - 0.7) across R1 gives us a current of I(R1) = 11.3/93.7k = 0.120598mA

By Kirchoff's law the difference in current must be the base current 0.12 - 0.11 mA (2dp) = 0.01mA

**Task 2** - the collector current

We know that current gain is 100 (given)

So Ic = 100Ib  = 100 * 0.01mA = 1mA

**Task 3** - find the voltage at the collector.

By Ohms law the voltage drop across Rc = Ic*Rc = 1(mA) * 6k = 6V

So the voltage at the collector (with respect to ground is 12 - 6 = 6V

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the help. I didn't realise you can just disconnect the base to get the resistance for R2. And do you just ignore R(S) because of the capacitor?

Comment: @Physicsman no problem - I don't usually give a (full) answer to homework questions but I thought this might be useful example for tackling similar problems for anyone starting out. Learning to break down a problem into smaller (easier) steps is far more important than just getting 'the right answer'. Good luck with your studies.

Comment: Thanks. I have an exam in 12 hours and am just clearing up the things I don't understand: Could you check a question called: "Amplifier Gain. OP amp?" It hasn't really been answered yet and it seems like its a simple method